# Number of processes in a docker container on linux

Tags: docker, process, containers

Is docker container designed mainly for one process use?
Can a docker container contain many different and not related processes in it?

How people implement Inter Process Communications between processes out of a container and processes inside the container? Can I use shared memory, shared mutex between process in and out of one container? What about message queue or pipe? I believe I definitely can use TCP/UDP sockets or UDS sockets.

I wonder for linux but knowledge about Windows would welcome!

Comment: Standard practice is to run only one process per container, and to communicate over TCP (frequently HTTP).  Other things you describe are _possible_, but require much more setup, don't necessarily work on other container platforms (_e.g._, Kubernetes), and can be harder to administer or operate.

Comment: @David Maze Thank you! I see. I am learning docker. It's interesting!